# Where are my points?

Tags: support

I have answered a couple of questions today and received upvotes.  However, these upvotes aren't getting added to my grand total as if there is some kind of a cap.  This started happening after I've acquired the mortarboard badge.

I'm also seeing this on my Rep screen:
[image]

I've always seen the upvotes get added to the total realtime, so I'm curious why I'm not getting the points all of a sudden.

I've scoured the Help pages, but haven't been able to find anything in the official SE rules on such caps.

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With a few exceptions you can only 200 reputation per day.

Per https://tridion.stackexchange.com/helpcenter/whats-reputation:

> You can earn a maximum of 200 reputation per day from any combination
>   of the activities below. Only bounty awards and accepted answers are
>   not subject to the daily reputation limit.

You are at the limit already for the day. Actually you are over it due to two accepted answers:

[image]

Comment: ah, skimmed through that page too quick and didn't see the answer I was looking for.  Thank you.

Comment: I won't vote on you that much anymore @nick, then it won't happen in the future ;o)

Comment: +1 to @BartKoopman's point. :-P